# Capturing monitor with mss, and openCV

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, oop

I am trying to have a constant loop of screen capture in the openCV window..

I need the screenshots to be fast, and I am on Mac or I would use the windowsGui api..

I am getting a error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 13, in <module>
    with mss as sct:
AttributeError: __enter__
```

Current Code:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
from time import time
from PIL import ImageGrab
from mss import mss

loop_time = time()

with mss() as sct:
    monitor = {"top": 40, "left": 0, "width": 800, "height": 640}

    while(True):
        with mss as sct:

            screenshot = np.array(sct.grab(monitor))
            screenshot = cv.cvtColor(screenshot, cv.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

            cv.imshow('Computer Vision', screenshot)

            print('FPS {}'.format(1 / (time() - loop_time)))
            loop_time = time()

            if cv.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
                cv.destroyAllWindows()
                break


print('Done.')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out the issue, The error was being thrown because I had two with statements..

So the correct code would be :

```
    loop_time = time()

with mss() as sct:
    monitor = {"top": 40, "left": 0, "width": 800, "height": 640}

    while(True):

        screenshot = np.array(sct.grab(monitor))
        screenshot = cv.cvtColor(screenshot, cv.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

        cv.imshow('Computer Vision', screenshot)

        print('FPS {}'.format(1 / (time() - loop_time)))
        loop_time = time()

        if cv.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
            cv.destroyAllWindows()
            break


print('Done.')
```